# Netezza find the logged in database of my session

Tags: netezza

Looking for a way to find the database my session is logged into.

Postgres method below didn't work.

Select current_database()

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the name of the logged in database.

```
select database from _v_database where objid =current_db
```